# Error in my MySQL Syntax, what am I missing?

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO 'tblJobNumbers' 
VALUES (NULL, '3006', '05', 'THISTHS', 0, 'JOBLOCATION', '', '', 
        'JOBCOMMENTS', 'ES', '01/14/2013', '01/15/2013, 
        '', '', '', 'CRS-2', '25000')
```

There's my statement

```
  jobID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'referenced by tblJobResources.jreJobID',
  jobNumber int(4) NOT NULL,
  jobPrefix int(2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'reference tblJobPreix.jprID',
  jobCustomerTID varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  jobCustomerID int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'reference tblCustomers.cusID',
  jobLocation text NOT NULL,
  jobContactName text NOT NULL,
  jobContactInfo text NOT NULL,
  jobComments text NOT NULL,
  jobSoldBy varchar(2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'reference tblUsers.userID',
  jobStartDate varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  jobEstCompleteDate varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  jobCompleteDate varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  jobAcctgMethod text NOT NULL,
  jobBillMethod text NOT NULL,
  jobProduct varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  jobProductAmount varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (jobID)
```

There's my table dump showing layout and datatypes. What am I missing? Please someone help, this is my work's laptop and I don't think "but the stupid code" is a valid excuse for destroying company property.

Error Message:

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''tblJobNumbers' VALUES (NULL, 3006, 05, 'THISTHS', 0,
>   'JOBLOCATION', '', '', 'JO' at line 1.

Comment: And what error do you get...?

Comment: How do you perform the query?

Comment: error is: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''tblJobNumbers' VALUES (NULL, 3006, 05, 'THISTHS', 0, 'JOBLOCATION', '', '', 'JO' at line 1. Query is performed in PHP, this is the echo of the query (it was actually designed using PDO prepared statements, I couldn't get it to work, so I re-wrote it minus prepared statements and echoed the results to see if I could see anything obvious.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove single quotes around the tableName, it will be converted to a string. (*not a table anymore*)

```
INSERT INTO tblJobNumbers
         -- ^ remove single quotes
VALUES (NULL, '3006', '05', 'THISTHS', 0, 
'JOBLOCATION', '', '', 'JOBCOMMENTS', 'ES', '01/14/2013', 
'01/15/2013', '', '', '', 'CRS-2', '25000')
        -- ^ add single quote here
```

also, as you can see you have forgot to close the single quote around the date value.

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3983c/1)

Comment: That missing single quote would be it. I actually didn't have the single quotes around the table name originally (when I started having this problem 2 hours ago) and then added them because when I generated PHP from phpMyAdmin it put quotes around the table name so I thought maybe it needed it. Thank you so much, I don't know how I missed that single quote. This laptop also likes to thank you, as it gets to continue its life.

Comment: you're welcome `:D` by the way, i added sample demo on the sql fiddle.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal it's fine, since he supplied `NULL` on it. i tested it on fiddle and it worked fine `:)`

Comment: @JW. Sorry, just realised that, but how is this fine in mysql. It is defined as `NOT NULL` and `PRIMARY KEY`?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal it's because it was set as `AUTO_INCREMENT`. and this is the only time `NOT NULL` can be inserted with `NULL`. if `AUTO_INCREMENT` wasn't set, it will generate an error.

Comment: Darn I missed my chance where I knew something. When defined as AUTO_INCREMENT it can be passed NULL because the DB will never see a NULL value as it automatically creates the value before insertion. I'm not 100% sure but I actually think you'll get an error if you pass it anything other than NULL.